# minimizing the image size

Tags: pdftex, wide-image

I want to minimize the image size in latex i tried so many times with different codes but non gave me the required result.
 here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering % l b r t
\includegraphics[trim=0.0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm, clip=true,
 width=\linewidth]
{Files/PN.pdf}
\caption{Petri nets components}
\label{fig:bb}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question, but you can try using either `scale=<scale factor` or `height/width = <desired size in one of the SI units>` within the `options` of `includegrapics`. Also welcome to TeX.SE, please add a fully compilable `MWE`.

Comment: Welcome between our community TeX.SE.

Comment: you are trimming 0cm off each edge, so that has exactly no effect at all, what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to make the size of the image smaller when i manipulate the high and the width no effect ocurre

Comment: You can use the `pdfcrop` tool to create a minimized version of the PDF and then include this one.

Comment: Or you could spend five minutes and redraw that image in tikz.

Answer (score 1):

for exercise (of using petri library)  i redraw your image:

[image]

it can be scaled by changing `scale` from 1 to desired size. The image was generated with the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, crop]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                automata,
                petri,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, % <--- here you can adjust image size
    transform shape,
    node distance = 8mm,
                > = Triangle,
     place/.style = {circle, semithick, draw, minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style = {thick, draw, minimum size=6mm},
pre/.append style = {shorten <=0pt}
                        ]
\node [place,tokens=2,
       pin=80:Place ]   (n1)    {};
\node [transition,pin={[xshift=-2.2mm]80:Transition},
       right=of n1]     (n2)    {}
            edge [pre]  (n1);
\node [place,
       right=of n2]  (n3) [] {}
            edge [pre]  (n2);
\path ([xshift=1.2mm] n1) coordinate[pin=280:Token] (aux)
      (n2) -- coordinate[pin=280:Arc] (aux)   (n3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(it take me slightly more than 5 minutes, since i use petri library first time :-) ). this code can be used inside `figure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering % l b r t
\begin{tikzpicture}[... ]
<image code>
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Petri nets components}
\label{fig:bb}
\end{figure}
```

or store above code as PN.tex and generated pdf file include in document with

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering 
\includegraphics{Files/PN.pdf}
\caption{Petri nets components}
    \label{fig:bb}
\end{figure}
```